# when i enter domain name http://oj.mbstu.ac.bd into browser then next it redirect to IP http://103.28.121.75/index.do why?

Tags: php, server, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName oj.mbstu.ac.bd
        ServerAlias www.oj.mbstu.ac.bd

        ServerAdmin webmaster@oj.mbstu.ac.bd
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       oj.mbstu.ac.bd 
103.28.121.75   oj.mbstu.ac.bd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yourname@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This is the proper configuration, but as i can see your document root /var/www/ includes the html, just remove the conf document and include you own index.

Then just restart the apache server

## sudo service apache2 reload